# Sound interaction between two applications

Tags: c#, xaml, audio, windows-phone-8

I have built a Windows Phone application with a video player to show a logo animation at startup.
If I launch an external application (like Spotify) with background audio (for example a song) and then switch to my application, the song is stopped (probably because of my logo animation) even though my logo animation doesn't even have audio.

I used a MediaElement for the logo animation :

```
<MediaElement AutoPlay="False" Name="media" Source="Assets/video.mp4"/>
```

In the code behind I use `media.play();` to start the logo animation.

Is there a way to avoid stopping the sound of other applications?

Comment: i'm a bit confused over the question. Are you having the player in the splash screen itself if i'm correct?

Comment: No, it's a fake splashscreen which show a logo animation before displaying Home screen.

Comment: So where are you having your `MediaElement`? and what's the issue you are having?

Comment: The first page loaded is just a `PhoneApplicationPage` with a `MediaElement` (logo animation). When animation is done, the Home screen is loaded. Problem is that when logo animation is playing, audio background (from other applications) is stopped.

Comment: SO what you're saying is the audio which is integrated with the logo animation is not working? Can you post your code? Is the `MediaElement` which you've posted above working properly?

Comment: thank you for your answer. My video doesn't have audio. If i launch an app (like Spotify for example), audio is playing in background. But when i launch my app, because of my video, the spotify song stop suddenly.

Comment: so... what you are saying is that you want to use sound for inter process communication, on a phone? that's a brave new concept :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> **When a MediaElement control plays audio or video content, any
>   background sounds or media already playing are halted.** The app
>   launches the playback experience when the user taps the control. Only
>   one MediaElement control can operate at a time.

What this means for you is that you need to redesign the logo to run via XAML animations or some other means besides `MediaElement` if you want background audio to function properly. Depending on where your animation is coming from, this might be simple for you or it might be outside your scope. You'll have to determine for yourself if the benefits of background audio (Pandora, Spotify, Podcasts, etc) outweighs the work required.

That being said, I've used a large number (probably 20% in my testing) of apps that cancel background audio every time you enter them, and it's extremely frustrating. I think most users would prefer you fixed your application so that background audio is not interrupted.